# Prevent acess to by typing the URL

Tags: javascript, html, iis-7.5

I know this question has posted several time. But I cannot solve my issue yet.

I have a exe which should only download through the download page. User should not be able to download it by typing the path to exe.

I am using IIS 7.5 and hosted it locally.

Is it possible to achieve this using URL Rewrite module in IIS?
(Is there any other easy way to do this)

Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use URL Rewrite module. If you need to stop direct download check for referrer. If referer comes only if you go through another page.Directly typed URLs does not have referre.

Comment: Can you please provide me some some links, which has some kind of tutorial.Thank You.